# Xamarin Form waiting for async task

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have an async void where I get the data I need to compare with local data then populate the listView.

```
CheckReservations(currentDate); //async void
BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel(); //the model
```

But obviously the model gets executed sooner than the async void, is there any way to wait for the void to finish and then populate the model? I have the `await` keyword before getting the HTTP response, but it is not helping, Documentation didn't do well for me thus far.

I changed my code to the following:

```
   protected async Task<ArrayList> CheckReservations(string day)
    {


        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            try
            {

                var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("reservation_day", day));
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
                var response = await _client.PostAsync(Url, content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
                    List<Reservations> myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reservations>>(json);
                    foreach(Reservations res in myData)
                    {

                     reservations.Add(res.reservation_time);
                    }
                    return reservations;

                }
                else  { return null;  }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("" + e);
            }
        }
        return reservations ;
    }
```

And the call to:

```
reservations =  (ArrayList) CheckReservations(currentDate);
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.ArrayList> to System.Collections.ArrayList.
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to change from async void to async task in order to make it awaitable. An async void method is a fire and forget method, for this reason, your model is created first.

Comment: I changed my code, now I have a different error.

Comment: You need to await your method

Comment: reservations =  await CheckReservations(currentDate);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an async void where I get the data I need to compare with local data then populate the listView.

If you have made this async void yourself I would suggest you change it with a Task instead, an async void is a bad practice, unless it's a lifecycle method.

```
await CheckReservations(currentDate); //async Task
this.BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel(); //the model
```

See to it that your CheckReservations method is a task,

```
   protected async Task<ArrayList> CheckReservations(string day)
{
    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
        try
        {
            var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("reservation_day", day));
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
            var response = await _client.PostAsync(Url, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
                List<Reservations> myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reservations>>(json);
                foreach(Reservations res in myData)
                {
                 reservations.Add(res.reservation_time);
                }
                return reservations;
            }
            else  { return new ArrayList();  }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("" + e);
            return new ArrayList();
        }
    }
    return reservations ;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works, turns out I didnt get a good response because my ArrayList wasnt initiated.

Comment: Well yeah pretty much

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `await` keyword when calling an `async` method

```
reservations =  await CheckReservations(currentDate);
```

Comment: I am calling that in constructor so I am having an error where I can only call await in an async method.

Comment: try calling it from OnAppearing instead

Comment: Now the reservations arraylist isnt populated anymore